# Containing element's width is not displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Several images are placed into an element whose display is flex and flex-wrap set to nowrap. The images don't fit into the element's width and extend beyond the screen width.

I am trying to calculate the width of the element that includes the images. However the width of element is always equal to screen width whereas it should be much greater than screen width.

Several threads have advised to first check if all the images have been loaded. Following is the code used to check the loading of the images.

```
let len = allCarousalImagesList.length,
    counter = 0;

[].forEach.call( allCarousalImagesList, function( img ) {
    if(img.complete)
      incrementCounter();
    else
      img.addEventListener( 'load', incrementCounter, false );
} );

function incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
    if ( counter === len ) {
        let carousalWidth = carousalElement.offsetWidth;
        let browserWidth = window.innerWidth;
        console.log(browserWidth, carousalWidth);
    }
}
```

Inspite of checking for the loading of images, the width of the element containing unwrapped images is not being displayed correctly and is equal to screen width. I am using offsetWidth to get the width. Please help with this issue.

The code has been uploaded on the codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-bash-0riup)

Answer (score 0):

So I created a solution to your problem:
And make sure to add *position:absolute;* to your carousal class

```
   window.addEventListener("load", function () {
      let carousalElement = document.getElementsByClassName("carousal")[0];
      var width_of_img_container = window.getComputedStyle(carousalElement).width;
      console.log(width_of_img_container);
    },false);
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the fix you suggested. Here is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-bas-3hwuw. However there is no log statement (given in the event listener function) printed when the website is run.

Comment: unfortunately the code does not work so good in codesandbox but in non-web code editor it works perfectly fine. Like VSC or Notepad++. Try it out.